# Unable to connect to MFP Server 8.0 - Invalid Security Check RegisteredClient

Tags: android, cordova, mfp

I have created one sample cordova based MFP app and trying to connect to the MFP server but it is failing, Below are the steps that i followed.

> 1. Created cordova app with MFP template using cordova create sample --template cordova-template-mfp
> 2. Added Android platform using Cordova platform add android
> 3. Added MFP Plugin using, cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp
> 4. Finally added WL.Client.connect inside wlCommonInit

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.Client.connect({
        onSuccess : onConnectSuccess,
        onFailure : onConnectFailure
    });
}

function onConnectSuccess(res){
    alert("connected successfully!");
}

function onConnectFailure(err){
    alert("sorry!");
    console.log(err);
}
```

When running the app onConnectFailure is called, and getting the below error

> { errorCode:"SECURITY_CHECK_NOT_FOUND" errorMsg:"Invalid Security
>   Check RegisteredClient"
>   responseText:"{"errorCode":"SECURITY_CHECK_NOT_FOUND","errorMsg":"**Invalid
>   Security Check RegisteredClient**"}" status:400 statusText:"Bad Request"
>   }

Able to access the MFP Server from mobile browser, below are the versions

> 1. mfpdev version = 8.0.0-2017102406
> 2. mfp plugin version  8.0.0.00-20171219-120008
> 3. MFP server console Product version: 8.0.0.00-20161020-040309

Please suggest.